# Using the right search method in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, json, windows, search, windows-runtime

I'm creating a Windows 8 app that can upload content from the local machine into the app (for local storage). I need to search through this content. What is the preferred strategy to use to incorporate this search functionality?

I have been trying to use the SampleData.json and SampleDataSource.cs from the grid template app as a starting point, but to me, it seems like the SampleData.json file will need to be updated each time new content is added to the app, seeing that data is populated from the SampleData.json file.
I have been going through the tutorial from  [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj655409.aspx)

Is there any other tutorials or advice anyone has for me? I need to incorporate this asap

Answer (score 0):

Windows can index files for you, and then you can use the [StorageFolder.CreateFileQuery[WithOptions]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227255.aspx) APIs to search via properties. If you place content inside a folder called "Indexed" in local or roaming app data, then indexing happens automatically and queries execute very quickly. You can also store the content in "appcontent-ms" files if that works better.

There's also the `[Windows.Storage.Search.ContentIndexer][2]` API for nonfile content or content that can't live in Indexed appdata folders. The ContentIndexer has its own query methods.

For all the details, see the section "Indexing and Searching Content" in Chapter 15 of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2). Even though it's using JS as the language, much of the book is just about WinRT so it's entirely useful even if you're working with C#. And it's free, so there's nothing to lose!